# How to delete the last column of an html table with varying columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabulated list of records - an HTML table.

Most rows have 3 columns but some may have just 1 or 2. In this case, I use colspan and stretch it across the other columns.

What I want to do:
When a user clicks a button on the page, I want to remove the last column (collapse), ONLY if it has more than one column.

How is this possible with jquery (if it can be done)?

Comment: can you please share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you should also add a class to the table so that you can select the table you want by class.

```
if($('tr').length > 1) {
   $('tr').each(function(){
      $("td:last").hide()
   })
}
```

If you add for example the class myTable, do:

```
if($('.myTable tr').length > 1) {
   $('.myTable tr').each(function(){
      $(".myTable tr td:last").hide()
   })
}
```

Comment: The same code in a single row `$(".myTable tr td:last").hide()`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$('tr').each(function(){
   $("td:last").hide()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  $("td:last").hide();
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think your method will remove even the column that is the only one in a row... Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to live the save number of columns (colspan) in the row before removing the latest column in order to make table responsive.

Wrote a little function. Not tried in action

```
<button onclick="removeLatestCol()"></button>

<script>
function removeLatestCol() {
    var latest_row = $("table tr:last");
    var cols = $("td", latest_row);

    if (cols.length == 1) {
        latest_row.remove();
        return;
    }

    var latest_col = cols.filter(":last");
    latest_col.prev().attr("colspan", (latest_col.prev().attr("colspan") || 1) + (latest_col.attr("colspan") || 1));
    latest_col.remove()
}
</script>
```